# In Apple Safari 14.0.3 Javascript will not set cookie expiry more than one week in future

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, safari

This is my second time asking this question, but I have much more information to offer as a result of a lot of trial and error experimentation.

I have tried various ways to set a cookie in Safari using javascript 'document.cookie='

Using the following variables/values…

```
var php_timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000); // for cookie value

var oneYearFromNow = new Date();
oneYearFromNow.setFullYear(oneYearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
var expiryDate = oneYearFromNow.toUTCString(); // for cookie expiry date
```

Various alternative approaches I've tried include…

Constructing the assignment expression from concatenated strings and variables.

```
document.cookie = "reminder=" + php_timestamp + ";expires=" +expiryDate + ";path=/;";
```

Interpolating variables into the assignment expression.

```
document.cookie = `reminder=${php_timestamp};expires=${expiryDate};path=/;`;
```

Literal string values as assignment expression.

```
document.cookie = "reminder=1615209245;expires=Tue, 10 Mar 2022 00:00:00 UTC;path=/;";
```

All variations produce the same result:

Chrome, Opera, and Firefox set the cookie with the desired expiry date.

Safari will not set a cookie expiry date more than 1 week into the future using javascript, but the same data can be used to set the cookie successfully using PHP.

With javascript in Safari, any expiry date further than one week in the future is set with a default expiry date value exactly one week from the date of setting the cookie.

Using javascript in Safari, expiry dates less than one week in the future work as expected.

I've tried using the 'max-age=' parameter instead of 'expires=', but the result was the same.

Is anyone able to reproduce this?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a known Safari issue: https://www.cookiestatus.com/safari/#other-first-party-storage (it's exactly as you figured out: client-side code cannot set cookies that last longer than a week)

Comment: Thank you Chris G. The silence in response to my earlier question wasn't helping. I've searched everywhere for something, but was unable to find anything about it on the Apple developer forum. My work-around will probably involve making the adjustment with PHP. I thought I was gong insane.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris G, I've written a workaround using PHP to adjust the incorrectly set expiry date of the cookie.

After the cookie is set by javascript in response to a user action, the following code is run, making the needed adjustment.

```
<?php
// client-side script (in Safari) cannot create a cookie
// with an expiry later than a week hence
// the cookie has been created, but has the wrong expiry date
// workaround: adjust the cookie expiry date using server-side script

// if the cookie is set
  if(isset($_COOKIE['reminder_requested'])){
  // get the value (the original date on which cookie was set)
    $value = $_COOKIE['reminder_requested'];
  // calculate the date six months from the date set
    $expiry = $value + (DAY_LENGTH * 182); // DAY_LENGTH is 1 day expressed as seconds
  // rewrite the cookie with adjusted expiry date
    setcookie('reminder_requested', $value, $expiry, "/");
}
?>
```